# Ant Script (qnx.xml) fails while packaging BB10 build

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, blackberry-10, ant-contrib

I have created an application for BB10 using IBM Worklight. The application version currently on production in v1.0. The application descriptor has version 1.0 for BB10.

I want to promote a new build with version 1.1. But, before releasing the build, I want to create interim builds for testing. Ex: 1.001, 1.002 and so on.

I am using antcontrib qnx.xml to package and sign blackberry 10 builds. When using this build process, the blackberry10 build fails stating: Native Packager exception occurred.

Also, from Worklight perspective, the versions that we can provide is only in format x.y. We cannot have x.y.z as the version in the application descriptor.

In such a situation, how do I fix this issue of releasing interim builds with version 1.001, 1.002 and then release the final build 1.1?

Answer (score 0):

1. You mention an exception, but do not provide any other details such as reproduction steps. Not helpful.
2. What makes you think that in application-descriptor.xml you can only use x.y as the version number? I used 1.0.1 and 1.0001 w/out any issues. You'll need to better explain your issue.

   ```
   <blackberry10 version="1.0.1"/>
   ```

[image]